# Is there a Pandas function that allows me to turn values into Dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe from an api response that gives me another body of data inside a column as shown:

[dataframe items column output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52N57.png)

Source code that outputs this is:

```
fill = client.get_fills()
fills = pd.DataFrame(fill)
fills = fills['items']
print(fills)
```

Is there a pandas function that extracts some of these values to columns? If not, what would be the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: are you trying to export the df to a csv?

Comment: Can you confirm if the datatype of items in `fills['items']` column is `dict`, or is it just a `str`?

Comment: Please show the type of object: `type(fill)`

Comment: @Phillyclause89 the datatype of items is a str

Comment: Thanks @ManiAllie I updated my answer to reflect that info. Basically just `import ast` and do `fills['items'] = fills['items'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` to convert the `str` to `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to export to a CSV, so

```
[dataframeName].to_csv(filePath)
```

might be what you're looking for.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `fills['items']` column contains `dict` objects and all of them have the same keys, you could explode those out into their own columns doing something like this:

```py
fill = client.get_fills()
fills = pd.DataFrame(fill)

# Will make a new df with each key corresponding to a column.
items_df = pd.concat(
    fills['items'].apply(
        lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
            {k:[v]for k,v in x.items()}
        )
    ).values
).reset_index(drop=True)

# If you would like to replace the original column with the columns from the new df
# while keeping other columns that may be in the df, otherwise just reassign fills above:
fills = fills.drop(columns="items").join(items_df)
```

**Edit**:
OP confirmed that the datatype is `srt` not `dict` for the data in the `fills["items"]` column. If that's the case and all the `str`s are valid python syntax for making a `dict` as they appear to be in the screenshot then you can `import ast` and use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string to dict prior to exploding it out.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

# Example of conversion happing during the apply method call
x= "{'KA3':'VA3','KB3':'VB3','KC3':'VC3'}"
print(type(x),x)
x=ast.literal_eval(x)
print(type(x),x)


# Test fills DataFrame
fills = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    items=[
        "{'KA':'VA0','KB':'VB0','KC':'VC0'}",
        "{'KA':'VA1','KB':'VB1','KC':'VC1'}",
        "{'KA':'VA2','KB':'VB2','KC':'VC2'}",
        "{'KA':'VA3','KB':'VB3','KC':'VC3'}",],
    other_col=[1,2,3,4],
    ))


# Convert the strings to dict using ast.literal_eval  
fills['items'] = fills['items'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Expolde the dicts out into 
items_df = pd.concat(
    fills['items'].apply(
        lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
            {k:[v]for k,v in x.items()}
        )
    ).values
).reset_index(drop=True)

# If you would like to replace the original column with the columns from the new df
# while keeping other columns that may be in the df, otherwise just reassign fills above:
fills = fills.drop(columns="items").join(items_df)
```

[Example code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20ast%0A%0A%23%20Example%20of%20conversion%20happing%20during%20the%20apply%20method%20call%0Ax%3D%20%22%7B%27KA3%27%3A%27VA3%27,%27KB3%27%3A%27VB3%27,%27KC3%27%3A%27VC3%27%7D%22%0Aprint%28type%28x%29,x%29%0Ax%3Dast.literal_eval%28x%29%0Aprint%28type%28x%29,x%29%0A%0A%0A%23%20Test%20fills%20DataFrame%0Afills%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20items%3D%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA0%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB0%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC0%27%7D%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA1%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB1%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC1%27%7D%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA2%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB2%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC2%27%7D%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA3%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB3%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC3%27%7D%22,%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20other_col%3D%5B1,2,3,4%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29%29%0A%0A%0A%23%20Convert%20the%20strings%20to%20dict%20using%20ast.literal_eval%20%20%0Afills%5B%27items%27%5D%20%3D%20fills%5B%27items%27%5D.apply%28ast.literal_eval%29%0A%0A%23%20Expolde%20the%20dicts%20out%20into%20%0Aitems_df%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%0A%20%20%20%20fills%5B%27items%27%5D.apply%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lambda%20x%3A%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bk%3A%5Bv%5Dfor%20k,v%20in%20x.items%28%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29.values%0A%29.reset_index%28drop%3DTrue%29%0A%0A%23%20If%20you%20would%20like%20to%20replace%20the%20original%20column%20with%20the%20columns%20from%20the%20new%20df%0A%23%20while%20keeping%20other%20columns%20that%20may%20be%20in%20the%20df,%20otherwise%20just%20reassign%20fills%20above%3A%0Afills%20%3D%20fills.drop%28columns%3D%22items%22%29.join%28items_df%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=2&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

**Edit 2**:
You could also do all in a single `.apply` call:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

# Test fills DataFrame
fills = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    items=[
        "{'KA':'VA0','KB':'VB0','KC':'VC0'}",
        "{'KA':'VA1','KB':'VB1','KC':'VC1'}",
        "{'KA':'VA2','KB':'VB2','KC':'VC2'}",
        "{'KA':'VA3','KB':'VB3','KC':'VC3'}",],
    other_col=[1,2,3,4],
    ))

# Explode the dicts out
fills = fills.join(
    pd.concat(
        fills['items'].apply(
            lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
                {k:[v]for k,v in ast.literal_eval(x).items()}
            )
        ).values
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
).drop(columns="items")
```

[python tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20ast%0A%0A%23%20Test%20fills%20DataFrame%0Afills%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20items%3D%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA0%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB0%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC0%27%7D%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA1%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB1%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC1%27%7D%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA2%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB2%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC2%27%7D%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7B%27KA%27%3A%27VA3%27,%27KB%27%3A%27VB3%27,%27KC%27%3A%27VC3%27%7D%22,%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20other_col%3D%5B1,2,3,4%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29%29%0A%0A%23%20Expolde%20the%20dicts%20out%20into%20single%20row%20DataFrames%20and%20concat%20them%0Afills%20%3D%20fills.join%28%0A%20%20%20%20pd.concat%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fills%5B%27items%27%5D.apply%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lambda%20x%3A%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bk%3A%5Bv%5Dfor%20k,v%20in%20ast.literal_eval%28x%29.items%28%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29.values%0A%20%20%20%20%29.reset_index%28drop%3DTrue%29%0A%29.drop%28columns%3D%22items%22%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)